# `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, NOFOLLOW">` but only for external links - without using `rel="nofollow"`

Tags: nofollow

Can you set `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, NOFOLLOW">` but only apply the nofollow part to external links ?

I know you can set `rel="nofollow"` on individual links, but in this particular instance i dont want to touch the links, but set a global nofollow for all outgoing links ?

Comment: You would need to use it on the individual links you wish to add it to. It's either all or nothing on the meta tag level.

Comment: @John why not post that as an answer? Surely you know how this site works by now? ;)

Answer (score 1):

The meta robots tag applies to the whole page. If you add the `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, NOFOLLOW">` to the page then first of all it won't work as it is incorrect, secondly the links will in fact be followed. To prevent links from being indexed the only way if they are not linking to other pages within your site is to use the `rel="nofollow"` attribute. If the links link to pages within the site then you could add the meta robots tag to the header of those pages but only if you don't want them indexed at all, not if you only don't want them indexed in relation to one of the linking pages.